# DexGuard the submodule of a project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

We have the following setup:

- We build and ship an Library for our clients. The SDK is obfuscated with DexGuard
- That Library is also used in our application. Our application should use the same AAR file that is shipped also to the clients that is obfuscated.
  Till version 2.3.* of Android plugin it was building the AAR file and reusing then that library for the app. From version 3.0 it does not seems to be the case. I have the feeling that it is using directly the files.

Is there a way to force the same process - to build the AAR and then to use it from the app?

Thanks and Kind Regards

Comment: Is your library already obfuscated when you consume that in your application?

Comment: It should be. The only solution that I found is to use Composite build. My problem with it was that the performance during the development is affected, so I ended up with 2 configurations - one is used for the development - no DexGuard. And the other one is used for the release build it seems to be working fine in that way